# How to vertically center align div having back ground image

Tags: html, css

I have an outer `div` and an inner `div`. Inner `div` has `background-image`.

How to vertically center align inner div `image`?
I dont want to use `margin-top`

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcUHb/250/)

Comment: use **flex** , as [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/mcUHb/252)

Comment: I have `span` and `div` [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcUHb/262/).

Comment: @ozil: I updated my answer..

Comment: Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/mcUHb/264/

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS. You'll have that Google logo centered vertically.

```
#imgDiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid blue;

    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -o-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-50%);
    transform: translatey(-50%);
}
```

Comment: I have `span` and `div` [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcUHb/262/).

Comment: What are you trying to do now?

Comment: both vertically align as `span` is aleady

Comment: Your span is not really vertically center. You used 400px as line-height. If screen's/container's height increases it wont be in center.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate this with some simple CSS. Use the "position" property.

```
#parentDiv {
    position: relative;
}

#childDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: I have `span` and `div` [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcUHb/262/).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcUHb/259/)**

Updated [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mcUHb/263/) as per your requirement:  **Note:** If the text height increases, the background image will move upwards

```
div.outer {
display:table;
border: 1px solid red;
height:300px;
width:300px
}
.inner {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:normal;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#imgDiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#spanid {
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div id="imgDiv"></div> <span id="spanid">Some text....</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have `span` and `div` [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcUHb/262/).

Comment: I want `google` image to align with `span` (moves down to span level)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to set the height of #imgDiv to height:100%; and then set the background-position to center, center.

```
#imgDiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-position:center,center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display` `flex` to make it working! Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/mcUHb/260/).

```
#imgDiv {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-image: url("http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .outerDiv {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        border: 1px solid red; 
        height:300px; 
        width:300px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent to add `display: table;`
Child to add `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;`.If you want `background` center `child to add` `background-position: center center;`

```css
#imgDiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative; border: 1px solid red; height:300px; width:300px; display: table;">
    <div id="imgDiv"> Hello Vertical Middle !! </div>
</div>
```